# modulo size_t yields "The result of expression ' ' is undefined"

Tags: c, clang, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

On a 64-bit system, when using the modulo operator along with size_t types, i get the following warning from the clang analyzer:

```
htable.c:38:62: warning: The result of the ' ' expression is undefined [clang-analyzer-core.UndefinedBinaryOperatorResult]
return ht->num_buckets > 0 ? (ht->hash_fn(key, ht->seed) % ht->num_buckets)
                                                         ^
```

[Complete trace](https://pastebin.com/UUdE3yZK)

The result of the hash function has size_t, and the number of buckets is also of size_t. Ultimately this translates into unsigned long.
AFAIK the result cannot be negative, I checked if the number of buckets is zero.

The hash function might overflow, but as it's used for a chaining hash table this does not lead to problems (if I am not mistaken).

What's wrong here?
Is this a false positive?

The function where the warning occurs:

```
static size_t
htable_bucket_idx(htable_t* ht, void* key)
{
    if (!ht || !key) {
        printf("htable - bucket_idx: Invalid Argument!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    return ht->num_buckets > 0 ? (ht->hash_fn(key, ht->seed) % ht->num_buckets)
                               : ht->hash_fn(key, ht->seed);
}
```

The hash function is a crudely simplified version of the FNV hash function:

```
size_t
fnv_hash_ul(const void* in, unsigned int seed)
{
    size_t             h     = seed;
    const unsigned int prime = 0xFDCFB7;
unsigned long ul = *((unsigned long*) in);

    return (h ^ ul) * prime;
}
```

The definition of `htable_t` (with other types omitted for succinctness, appending on request)

```
typedef size_t (*htable_hash)(const void* in, unsigned int seed);

typedef struct htable
{
    htable_hash      hash_fn;
    htable_keq       keq;
    htable_cbs_t     cbs;
    htable_bucket_t* buckets;
    size_t           num_buckets;
    size_t           num_used;
    unsigned int     seed;
} htable_t;
```

Call of the function:

```
static int
htable_add_to_bucket(htable_t* ht, void* key, void* value, bool rehash)
{
    if (!ht || !key) {
        printf("htable - add_to_bucket: Invalid Argument!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    size_t idx = htable_bucket_idx(ht, key);

    [...]
```

Compiler Information:

```
clang version 11.1.0
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
```

[htable.c on GitHub](https://github.com/SomeUserName1/master/blob/main/src/data-struct/htable.c)
[htable.h on GitHub](https://github.com/SomeUserName1/master/blob/main/src/data-struct/htable.h)

Comment: What's the definition of `htable_t`?  What compiler / version are you using and how are you calling it?

Comment: Updated the question with the required information.

Comment: @SomeUsername1 Is there any chance that function can be invoked when `ht->num_buckets` is uninitialized?

Comment: @Zoso I don't think so. On initialization of the hash table, `ht->num_buckets` is initialized to `8`. The function `htable_bucket_idx` is called on insertion, removal and retrieval (remove, insert, get). All three functions are only called on initialized `htable_t`s. Otherwise, they would `exit(-1)` as the memory for the buckets was not allocated.

Comment: @SomeUsername1 I tried a minimal example of your code sequence and it seems to work fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hz6K5M3xj) with `clang-tidy` enabled

Comment: @Zoso: With the [original code](https://godbolt.org/z/f9Tn8PEbq) the warning does occur.  Which is even stranger because the rest of the code shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: I played around with removing everything up to the point where the warning disappears. The warning appears if [both rehash and insert are added](https://godbolt.org/z/qcdr377MP). If [rehash is made non-static and insert is removed](https://godbolt.org/z/6jsc4M4hv), there is no warning, was well as [when rehash is removed](https://godbolt.org/z/qqzKvE57v).

Answer (score 1):

In deed, this seems to be a false positive. I was able to wipe out all warnings by changing htable_rehash() from:

```
static int htable_rehash(htable_t* ht)
{
...
    ht->num_buckets <<= 1UL;
...
}
```

to

```
static int htable_rehash(htable_t* ht)
{
...
    ht->num_buckets *= 2;
...
}
```

Weird.

Comment: I was playing with it a little and I also found that all sorts of apparently unrelated changes made the warning go away.  This might be worth a bug report for clang-tidy.

Comment: I'm curious what other changes caused the analyzer to change its behavior. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Adding a space lets the warnings reappear. An indication for a false positive is also the message 'The result of the ' ' expression is undefined' where the compiler is unable to state the complained expression.

Comment: Replacing `<<= 1UL` by `*= 2` or ` = 2 * ht->num_buckets` didn't resolve the issue.